# JSF 2: Redirect to external url and add header param

Tags: http, jsf, redirect, jsf-2, http-headers

I have current situation: We have a web application where the authentication/authorization is done using a Shibboleth SP (Service Provider) that connects towards an external Shibboleth IDP (IdentityProvider) and this works like a charm. Basically a call to a restricted part of the website is intercepted by Shibboleth and we are redirected towards an external website where we can log in with our eID.
After login, we are referred to the page by Shibboleth, with different header attributes being added by shibboleth related to the logged in user.
We create a UserPrincipal and place it on the SecurityContext of the application.

Now another application wants to login using the same Shibboleth and external eID page. So I thought to create a different url to be intercepted like /private/loginApp2

After being logged in, I refer the user towards an xhtml page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" >
    <f:metadata>
        <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{myBean.redirect}"/>
    </f:metadata>
</html>
```

And this is my bean:

```
@Component
@SessionScoped
public class MyBean {

@Autowired
private UserInformationBean userInformationBean;

public void redirect() throws IOException {
    final String jwtToken = JwtTokenCreator.createJwtToken(SecurityContext.getUserPrincipal());
    ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();

    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) ec.getRequest();
    MutableHttpServletRequest mutableRequest = new MutableHttpServletRequest(req);
    mutableRequest.putHeader("kid", jwtToken);
    ec.setRequest(mutableRequest);
    ec.redirect("http://external.url");
}
```

In the myBean, my initial plan was to

- get the loggedIn user (UserPrincipal) from the SecurityContext
- build a JWT (Json Web Token) based on the UserPrincipal properties
- add this JWT to the http header
- perform a redirect towards the other application

But as I understood, this doesn't seems to be possible to execute a redirect from the ExternalContext and keep the headers (since HTTP creates a new request?)
I could add the jwtToken as a queryParameter (which is encrypted by https) but I don't think this is a good idea either.

Does anybody have an idea what's the cleanest solution in my case?